# Cloudflare Bulk domain Add Automation

Tags: unix, cloudflare

Looking for cloudflare solution.
trying to bulkonbaord 20 domains into CF account.

I am on Windows 10 running flarectl package for Windows.
I was able to set the necessary keys and env.

Now I want to add more domains in bulk from a txt file.

The solution provided here is containing only the linux commands.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000841472-Adding-Multiple-Sites-to-Cloudflare-via-Automation

unable to execute or convert into windows.

for domain in $(cat domains.txt); do flarectl zone create --zone=$domain --jumpstart=false; done

Can anybody tell me the changes needed for Windows?
Kind regards and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a comma separated file "domains.txt" with the domains you plan to add to CloudFlare.
2. Open the command line and type (replacing path_to_file and path_to_flarectl accordingly):

```
set /P domains=<path_to_file\domains.txt

for %d in (%domains%) do (
  path_to_flarectl\flarectl.exe zone create --zone=%d --jumpstart=false
)
```

- Obs.: I've noticed a 50 entries limit.